# Unable to save Query Vars with a post

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, query-variables

I'm trying to save Query Vars to a post for later retrieval.

I'm using permalinks in this format: domain.com/%category%/%postname%/

Example:

1. I create a following page

   ```
   domain.com/page-003/
   ```
2. I add Query Var called **email** to the page

   ```
   add_query_arg('email', 'test@abc.com', 'domain.com/page-003/')
   ```
3. Now when I call

   ```
   get_permalink($post_id);
   ```

   I get

   ```
   domain.com/page-003/
   ```

   Instead of

   ```
   domain.com/page-003/?email=test@abc.com
   ```

What am I missing? Aren't Query Vars saved with a post?

Comment: get_permalink function retrieves slug/url only from the database for the object without any query vars... https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/ ... i suggest you get_permlink first, then add query_arg, and see if it works for your situation?

Comment: Like e.g. this example echo esc_url( add_query_arg( 'hello', 'there', get_permalink( 9 ) ) );   https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/

Comment: Oh i see you want to save query vars for later reterival for that you need to first save those values maybe as post_meta, and then you can reteive that and use as add_query... i write this in answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to save some meta data which you want to restore later on and add as query arg into the URL.

You need to first save it as post_meta like e.g. when you save post with that data. You use:

```
<?php update_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'email_address', 'abc@mail.com'); ?>
```

More details: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta

Then during the retrieval, you may hook into a HOOK early on like template_redirect or earlier of the post you can get post_meta to get the email and then add to query arg:

```
<?php $email = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'email_address' ); ?>
```

Then

```
esc_url( add_query_arg( 'email', $email, get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) ) );
```

Something like that, code is untested, I just wrote here, you may please read detailed doc in codex for each function used above.

**Update:** **How to update/fill Ninja form field from Meta Value:**

```
add_filter( 'ninja_forms_render_default_value', 'wm_the_value' , 10 , 3);

function wm_the_value( $default_value, $field_type, $field_settings ) {
    if( 'textbox' == $field_type && in_array('ref' , $field_settings)){
        $default_value = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'_listing_mls', true);
    }

    return $default_value;
}
```

'ref' is field name in Ninja form.
'_listing_mls' is meta_key name from WP database.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: When I do `esc_url( add_query_arg( 'email', $email, get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) ) );` I should see the Query Var in my address bar right? How come I still see the page without any Vars?

Comment: You need to add query_arg way earlier than page or URL is loaded. Like when doing wp_query or if you using defautlt loop, then you need to hook this add_query_arg into very early hook like : add_action( 'pre_get_posts' .. see this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/178492/30852

Comment: Also can I ask why you need it in the Query_ARG? if you are using $_GET to those values and use on the page, you may do not need to query_args, as you already have info in database, you may need just simple use get_post_meta and use that info wherever you need to use that info on the page if you are using $_GET to get that info...

Comment: a Ninja form on the same page reads the Query Vars and fills them in the fields.

Comment: Oh i have resolved that on a client's project, you do not need query var. Let me add the code I used using value from the Meta.. i edit above post. You can adapt that for your situation.

Comment: _You need to add query_arg way earlier than page or URL is loaded._ Could you help me on this further: I've added the `esc_url( add_query_arg( 'email', $email, get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) ) );` as the first thing in the page's template, right after `global $wp_query;` Is this what you meant? It still doesn't show it in the address bar. Sorry I'm not a developer.

Comment: Ok, I'd be happy to see that!

Comment: @Tom check the code I have added, i used that to fill ninja form field to pre-populate value from the meta_field.

Comment: Amazing! The ninja code works great! Thank you @Mohsin

Comment: @Tom great to know that!  Good Luck with your project :)